# Syntax Error while using Aysnc/Await in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am relatively new to Node.js I have ran myself into an error the code is:

```
async function loadingOneImage(file){
........
}


async function generateDataset() {
    const {image, target} = await loadingOneImage(file)
}

 generateDataset();
```

The structure of the code can be seen above. I have a function generateDataset() that is being called initially. Inside generateDataset() another function loadingOneImage() is being called. But once I run the program I run myself into the following error:

```
/home/nauyan/Desktop/EsperSolutions/TensorFlow.js/tfjs-examples/simple-object-detection/dataprep.js:85
                const {image, target} = await loadingOneImage(file)
                                        ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Can someone please advise me regarding this problem.

Comment: What Node version are you running?

Comment: I am using v10.16.0

Comment: Does it work if you define both your async functions like this instead? `const generateDataset = async () => { ...code }`

Comment: Otherwise, make sure your `generateDataset` isn't nested in another function that isn't async

Comment: Still the not working and generateDataset function isn't nested inside another function.